# Type issue making a linear-gradient mixin: Expected a color. Got: #d9d9d9 55%

Tags: css, sass, linear-gradients

I'm currently trying to utilize a slimmed down version of the SASS mixin described here, which helps implement linear-gradients: https://www.sitepoint.com/building-linear-gradient-mixin-sass/

My slimmed down version:

```
// @param {Keyword | Angle} $direction - Linear gradient direction
// @param {Arglist} $color-stops - List of color-stops composing the gradient
@mixin linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops...) {
  // Direction has been omitted and happens to be a color-stop
  @if is-direction($direction) == false {
    $color-stops: $direction, $color-stops;
    $direction: 180deg;
  }

  background: nth(nth($color-stops, 1), 1);
  background: linear-gradient($direction, $color-stops);
}
// Test if `$value` is a valid direction
// @param {*} $value - Value to test
// @return {Bool}
@function is-direction($value) {
  $is-keyword: index((to top, to top right, to right top, to right, to bottom right, to right bottom, to bottom, to bottom left, to left bottom, to left, to left top, to top left), $value);
  $is-angle: type-of($value) == 'number' and index('deg' 'grad' 'turn' 'rad', unit($value));

  @return $is-keyword or $is-angle;
}
```

When I utilize it, like so:

```
@include linear-gradient(#ededed 54%, #d9d9d9 55%);
```

I'm receiving a syntax error:

> Expected a color. Got: #ededed 54%

I believe the problem is with this line:

```
$color-stops: $direction, $color-stops;
```

because I noticed it works fine when I utilize it in this way:

```
@include linear-gradient(to top, #fff 50%, #f0f0f0 51%);
```

I believe I've worked it out to being a type issue, but can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/fb808baf545324248a8fc54f426d5b55

Comment: I tried updating SASS and Compass (and since I'm on Ruby on Rails sass-rails and compass-rails) to match those versions and still got the same error. However, I continued to explore my initial idea that it was a Type issue and I think I found the solution. See my posted answer/solution for full details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured out the solution.

To start, I quickly tested the current output of $color-stops by adding:

```
  &:after {
    @each $color in $color-stops {
      content: type_of($color);
    }
   }
```

This verified my concern as it output two different types, in the scenario that it ran though this code:

```
$color-stops: $color-stops, $direction;
```

It output:

> content: arglist; 
>   content: list;

Ultimately, I found the solution to this was to change the way I was appending the $direction variable.

Changed:

```
$color-stops: $direction, $color-stops;
```

To:

```
$color-stops: append($color-stops, $direction);
```

Now my test code output:

> content: list; 
>   content: list;

And not longer errors out.

Comment: I don't know why you have problems with arglist, is basically the same that a list but is a good solution if works for you.